# How to convert a txt file to a `json` object using Shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file, which I want to convert to a `json` object:

```
MAX_PDQPRIORITY:  80
DS_MAX_QUERIES:    50
DS_MAX_SCANS:      1048576
DS_NONPDQ_QUERY_MEM: 100000 KB
DS_TOTAL_MEMORY:   1000000 KB
```

My script outputs wrong and I have to manually edit it to `json`.

How do I use shell to make this change?

Desired output:

```
    [
            {
                     "MAX_PDQPRIORITY":"80",
                     "DS_MAX_QUERIES":"50",
                     "DS_MAX_SCANS":"1048576",
                     "DS_NONPDQ_QUERY_MEM":"100000",
                     "DS_TOTAL_MEMORY":"1000000"
            }
    ]
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# date:2019-02-02
# informix Show mgmdy .
LANG=EN
pathfile='/home/ampmon/agents/zabbix-agent/script/informix/text'
#expect mgm.#expect |grep -Ev 'Password:|spawn|Invalid' >$pathfile/mgm1.txt
cat $pathfile/mgm1.txt|grep MGM -A 8|grep -Ev 'MGM|-|^$' >$pathfile/mgm.txt
check=`cat $pathfile/mgm.txt|wc -l`

if [ $check -eq 0 ];then
   echo "No query results"
   exit 1
fi
MAX_PDQPRIORITY=($(cat $pathfile/mgm.txt|grep MAX_PDQPRIORITY |awk -F[:] '{print $2}'|awk '{print $1*1.00}'))
DS_MAX_QUERIES=($(cat $pathfile/mgm.txt|grep DS_MAX_QUERIES |awk -F[:] '{print $2}'|awk '{print $1}'))
DS_MAX_SCANS=($(cat $pathfile/mgm.txt|grep DS_MAX_SCANS |awk -F[:] '{print $2}'|awk '{print $1}'))
DS_NONPDQ_QUERY_MEM=($(cat $pathfile/mgm.txt|grep DS_NONPDQ_QUERY_MEM |awk -F[:] '{print $2}'|awk '{print $1}'))
DS_TOTAL_MEMORY=($(cat $pathfile/mgm.txt|grep DS_TOTAL_MEMORY |awk -F[:] '{print $2}'|awk '{print $1}'))

printf '\t[\n'

printf '\t\t{\n'

      printf  "\t\t\t \"MAX_PDQPRIORITY\":\"${MAX_PDQPRIORITY}\",\"DS_MAX_QUERIES\":\"${DS_MAX_QUERIES}\",\"DS_MAX_SCANS\":\"${DS_MAX_SCANS}\",\"DS_NONPDQ_QUERY_MEM\":\"${DS_NONPDQ_QUERY_MEM}\",\"DS_TOTAL_MEMORY\":\"${DS_TOTAL_MEMORY}\"}\n"


printf "\t]\n"
```

My current output:

```
        [
                {
","DS_NONPDQ_QUERY_MEM":"100000","DS_TOTAL_MEMORY":"1000000"}ES":"50
        ]
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Looks like your data file and/or your script contains CRLF line endings. You should use `dos2unix` on them to clean them up.

Answer (score 4):

If `jq` is available, please try:

```
jq -s -R '[[ split("\n")[] | select(length > 0) | split(": +";"") | {(.[0]): .[1]}] | add]' input.txt
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "MAX_PDQPRIORITY": "80",
    "DS_MAX_QUERIES": "50",
    "DS_MAX_SCANS": "1048576",
    "DS_NONPDQ_QUERY_MEM": "100000 KB",
    "DS_TOTAL_MEMORY": "1000000 KB"
  }
]
```

As an alternative, if `python` happens to be your option, following will work as well:

```
#!/bin/bash

python -c '

import re
import json
import collections as cl

list = []
with open("input.txt") as f:
    od = cl.OrderedDict()
    for line in f:
        key, val = re.split(r":\s*", line.rstrip("\r\n"))
    od[key] = val
list.append(od)
print (json.dumps(list, indent=4))
'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you determine they are wrong? Both works on my environment. How did you test?

Answer (score 0):

For a simple translation, try using awk; it only reads the file once:

```
BEGIN {
  print "{"
}

{
  name=substr($1, 1, length($1)-1)
  value=$2

  print "\t\""name"\":\""value"\","
}

END {
  print "}"
}
```

This strips the trailing colon from field 1, then prints the values surrounded by double-quotes. It also silently drops the units (KB), as your sample output indicates.

Comment: i am so sorry i can not know your script，could you tell me what is worong by my script

Comment: just save that code to a file and run `awk -f thatfilename < inputfile` to get the JSON output

Comment: [root@host test]# awk -f 1.sh < mgm.txt 
{
        "":"",
",      "MAX_PDQPRIORITY":"80
",      "DS_MAX_QUERIES":"50
",      "DS_MAX_SCANS":"1048576
        "DS_NONPDQ_QUERY_MEM":"100000",
        "DS_TOTAL_MEMORY":"1000000",
        "":"",
}

Comment: I'm no JSON expert, but the examples online did not have your surrounding square brackets; if those are required, let me know, and that's easy to edit in.

Comment: if you can  show in my ask about : I want to output is that is ok

Answer (score 0):

or perl:

1. with [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module

   ```
   perl -MJSON -lne '
           @F = split(/:?\s+/);
           $data{$F[0]} = $F[1]
       } END {
           print encode_json [\%data]
   ' file
   ```
2. without

   ```
   perl -lne '
           @F = split(/:?\s+/);
           push @data, sprintf(q{"%s":"%s"}, map {s/"/""/g; $_} @F[0,1]);
       } END {
           print "[{", join(",", @data), "}]";
   ' file
   ```